# F# Changing from mutable to ref

Tags: reference, f#, mutable

Working on a program that needs a mutable set.  When trying to put the set in a closure I get an error:

```
let mutable donefiles : Set<FileRecord> = Set.empty
let filestodo = Set.difference parms.FileSpecs donefiles
let errorFile (file: FileRecord) =
    donefiles <- Set.add file donefiles
```

> Error 40  The mutable variable 'donefiles' is used in an invalid way.
>   Mutable variables cannot be captured by closures. Consider eliminating
>   this use of mutation or using a heap-allocated mutable reference cell
>   via 'ref' and '!'.

Trying to convert "donefiles" into a ref, but can't seem to get the syntax right. Tried the obvious (to me) first:

```
let donefiles : Set<FileRecord> = ref Set.empty
```

but:

> Error 40  This expression was expected to have type
>       Set     but here has type
>       'a ref

What is the syntax I should use in this case?

Comment: Instead of a mutable reference to an immutable set could you use a mutable `HashSet<FileRecord>`?

Comment: It appears that HashSet does not have a difference function.

Comment: You can use `.ExceptWith` to remove a collections of items from a `HashSet<T>`.

Answer (score 4):

**First of all**, it seems that you're using an older version of F#. This limitation on mutable variables [was lifted in F# 4.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpteam/2014/11/12/announcing-a-preview-of-f-4-0-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-vs-2015/).

But in case you can't switch to a newer version, here's the answer to the actual question:

The function `ref` takes a value and returns a mutable cell. The type of such cell is `'a ref`, where `'a` is the type of the value.

So in your case, the `ref` function returns `Set<FileRecord> ref`, but you specifically annotated `donefiles` to have type `Set<FileRecord>`, so there's a conflict (this is what the compiler is telling you).

Simply adjust your type annotation, it will work:

```
let donefiles : Set<FileRecord> ref = ref Set.empty
```

To mutate a ref cell, use the `:=` operator:

```
donefiles := Set.add file !donefiles
```

Comment: It almost worked! With your change (thanks!) the variable declaration worked but the closure definition didn't: I get the error "The value is not mutable".  I tried `donefiles <- Set.add file donefiles`. then I tried `!donefiles <- Set.add file donefiles' and got "Invalid expression on left of assignment".

Comment: `donefiles := Set.add file !donefiles` worked (had to deref the var)